# Where is the best place to initialise parse in Android app

Tags: android, parse-platform, objectid

I'm working on an app that another colleague has written, originally he set up parse to be initialised in the Application class with this code:

```
    ParseCrashReporting.enable(this);

    Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);
    Parse.initialize(this, YOUR_APPLICATION_ID, YOUR_CLIENT_KEY);

    ParseUser.enableAutomaticUser();
    ParseACL defaultACL = new ParseACL();
    ParseACL.setDefaultACL(defaultACL, true);
    ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
}
```

However when I then try and get the object ID in the launcher activity it returns null, so I moved this code to the launcher activity and added a save callback to ensure I could get the object ID when i needed it. Before this I tried using paused threads to ensure that parse had finished initialising before calling getObjectId() but this didnt work.

So my question is, where is the best place to put this code? It now works fine (from preliminary tests) in the launcher activity, but my colleague says all parse initialisation must be done in the Application class as it can affect the rest of the apps functionality. Who is right?

EDIT:

I can get the object ID with the code in the application class only on second load, not the first, but I need it on first load

Comment: According to their documentation its in the Application class under onCreate method.

Comment: In Application class it is good. It seems you are not using that application class. Check your manifest. By the way, you are wrong , your teammate is perfect. Give him party :)

Comment: How can he be perfect if his code doesn't work @PankajKumar :p I put the code back in the Application class, but called saveInbBackground in the launcher activity and it works how it should

Comment: the best place where u can initialize the parse is class extending Application class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, I put the code to initialise parse back in the Application class but called
     ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().getObjectId()
in the launcher activity and it works fine

NOTE:
I have only been developing for android for 6 months so I am still a learner!